# Laravel symbolic link to storage

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-5.4

I have some problems creating a symbolic link with laravel to access some images that are in my storage ...

I store my images in the folder

```
storage\app\public\clients
```

where I have images 1.png, 2.png and so on ...

I used the php artisan command to create the link

```
php artisan storage: link
The [public/storage] directory has been linked.
```

now when i try to access in my view the following path does not work

```
<img id = "thumbnail" src = "{{asset ('clients / 1.png')}}" width = "150px"> </ img>
```

do I have to do anything else to gain access to the storage folder in public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will create a link between `public/storage` and `storage/app/public`.

So, change this:

```
{{ asset('clients/1.png') }}
```

To:

```
{{ asset('storage/clients/1.png') }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Thank you, I did not understand this detail! I'll wait the time and accept the answer